# How to replace URL when page is refreshed?

Tags: ajax, refresh

I am using ajax to reload just the #content on my page and pushing a fake /#pagename to the history. I want to be able to reset or replace the url to index.html when the page is refreshed because currently when you refresh, it messes everything up because it is trying to refresh url/#pagename which doesn't exist.

Here is what I have:

```
window.onunload=function(){
  window.location.assign("url");
};
```

Comment: `window.location = '/index.html#pagename';`

Comment: seems like the 'onunload' part is whats not working?